# How can I send self-signed certificate via REST (put it in to header?)

Tags: android, rest, security, certificate, self-signed

I am trying to send generated by my Android device self-signed certificate to server to authorize user. Could you tell me how to do it? Maybe I can attach to request header?

Answer (score 0):

that's not secure
OAuth2 protocol is the best way

first you send the user / pass to login 
server will pass back an authToken or accessToken which the mobile device will send back for all subsequent calls.

Comment: It is one security. Certificate should be another one. I want to send login, pass and cert to server. But I don't know how sohuld I do it.

Comment: why you want to send certification,with user/pass, too? it's not needed to be generated from client side... that's simple as i said
and how to do it?
from client side you just need to send some very simple HTTP request
and about server-side that's not my job :)